# Integral of two zero-order spline basis functions

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, convolution, spline

I try to derive the formula for the discrete convolution from the continuous convolution using piecewise constant interpolation.

Whereby the zero-order spline basis function is given as:

$$\phi^0(x) = \begin{cases} 1; \quad \text{ if } x \in [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}) \\
0; \quad \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The piecewise constant interpolation as:

$$u(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \phi^0(x-i) U_i$$

At some point I arrive at the equation:

$$(u*h)(k) = \sum_{l \in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} U_IH_m
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi^0(x) \phi^0(k-l - m-x) dx
$$

To get the correct result the following equivalence is needed:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi^0(x) \phi^0(k-l - m-x) dx = \begin{cases} 1; \quad \text{ if } m=k-l\\
0; \quad \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

However I don't totally get why this holds, can maybe someone help me with an intuitive explanation?